# TFS2017 compatibility with SQL2016 after upgrade

Tags: sql-server, tfs

We were working on TFS2015 and SQL2014. Our plan of this month is upgrading to TFS2017update1 and SQL2016.

I have created a test environment on personal VM. My process :

1. Back up TFS database in SQL, upgrade SQL2014 to SQL2016
2. Upgrade TFS2015 to TFS2017update1
3. Restore the database.

Everything works well except step #3. I was not able to restore the database back to TFS2017. Any suggestions?

The error info:

> TF30046: The instance information does not match. Team Foundation
>   expected 368f7830-1c67-4c4c-8bc4-ba3d5b5a5543 which was not found.
>   Please contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

Comment: This might provide some help... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/11/30/upgrade-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-2017/

Comment: Are you using the TFS 2017 Pre-production upgrade path? This will update your instance ID as the error suggests. If you restore a database backup from prior to the upgrade there is going to be an ID mismatch. Restore the database before you do the upgrade (though from what you have described I don't see why a restore is actually necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, suggest you to go through the event log on your machine to see if there are some useful info for troubleshooting.

> If you're using SQL Server 2016, we require a Visual C++ runtime
>   [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3138367/update-for-visual-c-2013-and-visual-c-redistributable-package) to be installed.

Double check your environment, make sure you have installed a Visual C++ runtime.

Besides, since you are going to update TFS 2017 Update 1, which the support SQL2016 version minimum is SP1.

```
TFS version Support  SQL Server version
TFS 2017 Update 1    SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1)
                     SQL Server 2014
```

More details please refer TFS [Requirements and compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements).

You could also follow Pero P.'s suggestion,select the Pre-Production upgrade, ignore the restore.

Comment: After reinstall the SQL server  and update to  SQL2016SP1 , issue resolved. Not sure which one is the root cause.Thanks!